What would the implications of a anti-gravity metal be?
I couldn't find a post on this, but I'm sure there's one like it somewhere.
Basically, what if there was a material that "fell" up instead of down? Let's call it Newtonium, and let's also say that other than the anti-gravity stuff it has the properties of iron.
What would a human civilization be able to accomplish with this material? I have a few ideas. Newtonium boots for high jumping, for example. You could have a disc of Newtonium chained to the ground, then let the chain go slack while someone is holding very tightly onto it to let them get a good view of the surrounding area. Then you winch them back down. You could almost certainly build some sort of perpetual motion machine with Newtonium, but I don't have the physics or engineering knowledge to figure out how that would actually work.
Obviously airships could be made with this. You would need a bit of extra lift so that you could adjust the airship to rise or fall. Probably a small helium/hydrogen or hot air balloon would do.
My main question is how an industrial (and a pre-industrial) civilization would change given abundant access to Newtonium. What sort of technologies would emerge and what would their implications be?

I’m voting to close this question because it's raw brainstorming, which is discouraged per the [help/on-topic]. It's open-ended, hypothetical, and leads to all answers being equal, all of which are prohibited by the [help/dont-ask]. Finally, it's an off-topic high concept quesiton (a seemingly small change that leads to vast changes, and we're expected to explain the vast changes).

Cavorite. H.G.Wells "The First Men In The Moon", 1901.

I think you could re-ask the question in a more focused way, such as "could this material be used for energy generation, and if yes, how?", "how could this material be used for transportation?", etc.

Antigravity is a funny thing. So easily can we imagine on an intuitive way, so hard are the contradictions in its science description. For example: imagine a pair planet where one of the planets gravitates negatively. One will be attracted by the other, while the other will be distracted by the first. Result is that the planet pair constantly accelerates into a direction without any limit. And that is only a small problem compared to the others.

How do you expect them to get to it? It would all fall off the planet.
Since your question seems to primarily talk about pre-industrial and industrial societies, let's talk about that. Pre-industrial societies will have obvious difficulties obtaining newtonium; if it exists in large quantities on the surface, where they can most likely access it easily, it will simply fall off the planet, while if it is in low-concentration quantities in the soil or deeper underground, it could conceivably stay held back by gravity, but it wouldn't be accessible to pre-industrial societies. An industrial-level society that can filter metal out of dirt might notice that some of the metal (newtonium) falls up instead of down, but that depends on someone happening to decide to search for valuable metals in the soil in a particular area where newtonium is common, which is unlikely but I'm sure it'd happen eventually (and if the hand of the All-Mighty Author wills it).
The most obvious application is airships. Why have those giant tanks of hydrogen (which can end in fire, if you've ever heard of the Hindenburg ...) when you can suspend yourself from a few bars of newtonium pulling you up? Of course gravity boots are a thing too, but anything without a lot of control systems and careful operation would fall apart because the constant force newtonium exerts on everything it touches would be hard to control; if you just slap some on the bottom of your boots, you'll find that when you take a step forward, you'd fall backward and your boots would come off your feet and go flying into the stratosphere. Generally, newtonium will be used for what it is used for in regular sci-fi: anti-gravity for airships and the occasional daredevil willing to work with the dangerous stuff.
But enough about what to do with it - your real issue will be explaining how it got there and how it's purified, if you plan on doing that. Newtonium can't be common, because if it is it would totally destabilize any mass bound to itself gravitationally. It might have been deposited by asteroid, but why the asteroid would fall towards Newtonland instead of away is a big question. It might have been created in some unimaginably-violent cosmic-scale event that changed the quantum physics of regular iron, but explaining how that didn't also wipe out all life in the surrounding megaparsec will be an issue.
